# MongoDB Find() is slow if several .NET Tasks run in the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, performance

I'm new in MongoDB ecosystem and faced with a problem using MongoDB on my ASP.NET MVC application. If I call Find method for a collection just once it works very fast, just a few milliseconds. But if I call the Find method several times in the same moment using Task.Run() it gets extremely slow and even could exceed 30 sec timeout.

Performance degradation numbers are like the following:

- a single query takes ~0.002 second to finish
- 4 parallel queries take ~3 seconds to finish (average duration is ~2.5 seconds)
- 40 parallel queries take 30+ seconds to finish and some of them are failed because of timeout (~18 seconds to finish in average).

If I run the same 40 queries one after each other without using tasks, all of them will complete less than in a second (~0.7 sec), i.e. the same ~0.002 sec per query.

What I have done already and it did not help:

1. No matter whether I create connection object inside the task code or create it once in the beginning and store in static field.
2. No matter which way I query the data:

   - `collection.AsQueriable().Where(...).Take(1)`
   - `collection.Find(Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(...)).FirstOrDefault()`
   - `collection.Find(m => ...).FirstOrDefault()`
3. Increasing timeout helps to avoid timeout exceptions but performance is still expectedly bad.

My environment:

I have very few data in my MongoDB collection (21 object, 1995 bytes total, 95 bytes per object average). The MongoDB server is at localhost environment, so network could not be an issue here. Server version is 3.2.4, works as Windows service. I get the same result using MongoDB hosted by linux VM in Azure. .NET MongoDB Driver is the last one and installed from nuget, the version is 2.3.0.157.

I cannot believe that such a mature system cannot handle few queries in the same time. So probably I have missed something. Could someone help and point me out the direction?

EDIT. The code sample I used for testing:

```cs
// IMongoDatabase database;
int iterations = 40;
var tasks = new Task<TimeSpan>[iterations];
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    var tempI = i;
    tasks[i] = new Task<TimeSpan>(() => {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        var integrationId = INTEGRATION_IDS[tempI];
        try {
            var metadataCollection = database.GetCollection<CacheMetadata>(METADATA_COLLECTION_NAME);
            var query = metadataCollection.AsQueryable()
                .Where(m => m.IntegrationId == integrationId)
                .Take(1);
            var metadata = query.FirstOrDefault();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            // Write elapsed time to the console
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            // Write the exception details to the console
        }
        return stopwatch.Elapsed;
    });
}

for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    tasks[i].Start();
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
// Write summary to the console
```

Comment: @JohnnyHK Added the code block from my test app

Comment: Thanks for adding the code; I'm able to reproduce this as well in LinqPad with the 2.2. driver, but only the first time it runs. All subsequent runs finish in milliseconds.

Comment: Just found out that pure threads instead of tasks work fine - no timeout exceptions are thrown.

Comment: One more thing. I found out that if I do some query in a moment when I create database connection in order to open it (probably there is a way to do it without fake query) and left the rest code the same, it works as expected without any timeout exceptions. Looks like the problem is that the driver cannot open the connection executing inside of a task while if there are number of tasks are working in the same time.

Comment: Right, I'm seeing the same thing. Sure seems like a bug in the driver.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I think so. Raised a bug in MongoDB jira: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1830. Thanks for your time.